# Ignore Int and String Properties if the value is 0 or string.Empty while indexing in ElasticSearch and Nest V7.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am working on ElasticSearch with .Net and I am new to ES. I am trying to index the fields/properties which comes from a POCO class. I want to ignore the index of the fields or property for which the value is `string.Empty` in case of string, or zero(0) in case of integer.

What can I do to ignore those fields/properties? I have read about `[Ignore]` decorator of Nest but it will ignore for all the documents, but i want if there is no value for that field/property only then ignore it.

Please Help!! Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: You may find [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/nest-avoid-storing-default-values-false-0-etc/140457/3) question useful.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for the answer.

Comment: @Rob, can u also look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58097471/script-params-doesnt-support-values-of-type-start-array-in-elasticsearch-v7-3 ?