# script params doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY in ElasticSearch v7.3 Update script

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I am trying to update the document for my index and getting the following error on update API script through Postman

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
                "reason": "[5:15] [script] params doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY"
            }
        ],
        "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
        "reason": "[5:15] [UpdateRequest] failed to parse field [script]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "x_content_parse_exception",
            "reason": "[5:15] [script] params doesn't support values of type: START_ARRAY"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

As the error is clearly stating that I am updating a field  in my document which has an array of data. Here is a sample

```
"hasParts": [
    {
        "documentLevel": 2,
        "levelProperties": {
            //some properties
        }
    },
    {
        "documentLevel": 3,
        "levelProperties": {
            //some properties
        }
    },
    {
        "documentLevel": 3,
        "levelProperties": {
           //some properties
        }
    },
    {
        "documentLevel": 3,
        "levelProperties": {
            //some properties
        }
    }
]
```

I want to update the above property using Update API for one of the document.

Can this be possible? If it is possible then what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in Advance for the help.

**EDIT:**
Here is the script

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.hasParts.add(params.haspart)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": [
      {
        "haspart": [
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          },
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          },
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          },
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          },
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `params` section must not be an array, but an object, use this script instead:

```
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.hasParts.add(params.haspart)",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
        "haspart": [
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          },
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          },
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          },
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          },
          {
            "documentLevel": 3,
            "levelProperties": {
              //some properties
            }
          }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```